# ms-access: date/time data type

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have a table that has a date/time field

when i display the report, should i make this column a GENERAL DATE? or something else? i  am having problems sorting

Comment: Why are you asking all these incredibly elemetary questions? Maybe you don't know about SuperUser.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display on the report will have no effect on the sorting.

(For sorting problems, can you tell more?)